# Ajax event error sometime when socket.on function work with node.js + express

Tags: ajax, node.js, express, socket.io

i using node.js + express + socket.io for do some ajax event after receive signal from socket, sometime it work but sometime failed when there have multi browser request at the same time. Here is my coding:

server:

```
var express = require('express'),
    app = express(),
    server = require('http').createServer(app),
    io = require('socket.io').listen(server);

server.listen(4000);

io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket){
    socket.on('send message', function(data){
        io.sockets.emit('new message', data);
    });
});
```

client:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var socket = io.connect();

jQuery(function($){
    socket.on('new message', function(data){
        if(data=='refreshNow'){
            $.ajax({
                type:"get",
                dataType:"json",
                url:"index.php?r=Ajax/TestBlankData",
                success:function(data){
                    console.log('success');
                },
                error: function() {
                    console.log('error');
                },
            });
        }
    });
});

$( "#testing" ).click(function() {
    socket.emit('send message', 'refreshNow');
});
</script>
```

ajaxpage:

```
public function actionTestBlankData()
{
    echo CJSON::encode(array());
}
```

console:

```
18 success
4 error
x GET http://localhost:5000/wwwroot/XHS/index.php?r=Ajax/TestBlankJson  jquery.js:8434
    send jquery.js:8434
    jQuery.extend.ajax jquery.js:7986
    (anonymous function) index.php:95
    EventEmitter.emit socket.io.js:634
    SocketNamespace.onPacket socket.io.js:2249
    Socket.onPacket socket.io.js:1931
    Transport.onPacket socket.io.js:1333
    Transport.onData socket.io.js:1304
    websocket.onmessage socket.io.js:2379
```

Comment: i don't even know what is the exact error

Comment: Script PHP in port 5000? Why not place the method "TestBlankJson" in app.js?

Comment: i place the method in client side because there is a component which need to be refresh by ajax request after others user update the data, its like real-time monitoring screen.

Comment: anyone? your help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Instead of using index.php could create a get method in your app.js. It would help to know how you have structured your project Node.js and PHP.

Comment: i still don't get your idea, can you provide more details?

Comment: what is the structure of your project node with php?

Comment: hi i found the problem, something wrong with my ajaxpage structure, its a yii framework structure actually but i had customize a bit to it and cause the issue, its my bad, anyway thanks for your help.